# is this simple proof by contradiction of uniqueness of prime factorization correct?

Tags: proof-verification, prime-factorization

I want to ask if the following proof correct. Assume that we have a prime factorization
$$
n=\prod_{i=1}^{r}p_{i}^{e_{i}}
$$

where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number, $e_i$ are non-negative integers, and $p_r$ is the largest prime number $\leq n$.

Suppose there also exists a set of non-negative integers $f_i$ such that

$$
n=\prod_{i=1}^{r}p_{i}^{f_{i}}.
$$

Hence, we have

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{r}p_{i}^{e_{i}} = \prod_{i=1}^{r}p_{i}^{f_{i}}
$$

Now suppose $f_k > e_k$ for some $1\leq k \leq r$. Dividing both sides by $p_k^{e_k}$, we have

$$
\prod_{i\neq k}p_{i}^{e_{i}}=p_{k}^{f_{k}-e_{k}}\prod_{i\neq k}p_{i}^{f_{i}}
$$

Clearly, $p_k$ divides the right-hand side, but does not divide the left. Hence, this contradiction means that our initial assumption that $f_k > e_k$ is impossible. By symmetry, we also cannot have $e_k > f_k$. Hence $e_i = f_i$ for all $i$, and the factorization is unique.

Comment: Where did you use that the $p_k$'s are prime numbers?

Comment: @egreg I know. In the case you did not understand, I asked the question to the OP.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos in the first two lines I say p_i are primes

Comment: Indeed, but where did you *use* that fact?

Comment: I used it near the end, when I say that the left-hand side cannot be divided evenly by p_k

Comment: Right! You should have stated it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof uses a fact that should be proved beforehand, namely that, for all primes $p$, if $p\mid ab$, then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$.

As such it is not fully correct. You can fix it using strong induction. If some number admitting distinct factorizations exists, then there is the minimum such $n$. Your argument shows that $n'=n/p_k^{f_k-e_k}$ also has distinct factorizations, which is a contradiction because $n'<n$.